# R list: how to extract column holding fixed other column

Tags: r, list

I have following data list.

```
a     b
200   111
200   222
201   333
201   444
```

I need to extract b from the list, given a = 200

```
data$b  %extracts b
data$a==200 %should hold a equal to 200
```

However, I do not know how to combine it.

I want to plot histogram of b, given a=200

Comment: Do you have a list or data frame)The way you subset suggests it's a data.frame object)? Just subset `hist(df[df$a==200,"b"])` and plot?

Comment: It does work, however I can't use it with ggplot

Comment: `ggplot` expects a data frame whereas base R `hist` expects a vector - just return the entire data frame. `ggplot(df[df$a==200, ], aes(b)) + geom_bar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ggplot you can pass in a subset of you dataframe. If you subset when you pass in the data this should work:

```
 ggplot(df[df$a == 200,]) + 
     geom_histogram(aes(b))
```

The idea is that `df$a  == 200` is a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values that tell `df[]` whether to include the row or not. When you pass in `df[df$a == 200,]` you're passing in a copy of `df` (because R is functional) with only the rows where `a == 200` . This is still a dataframe, so you can select `b` in the `aes()`  call.